# Como colocar um alerta variável no parâmetro onclick de um link? usando jquery e php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, if

Preciso colocar uma mensagem de produto indisponível em meu sistema, que pega o status de disponível da db (SIM ou NAO) fiz uma IF que muda a imagem do produto quando o status esta NAO mas quero uma mensagem caso o usuario clique nele dizendo que o mesmo esta indisponível..

Os produtos são puxados como lista do banco e todos ja tem um alert de confirmação quando um usuario clica, mas preciso que ele mude a mensagem se o item for indisponivel

Eis o que tenho: Exibe os produtos assim:

```
<a href="cadastra.php?cod=<?php echo $id_pro ?>&nome=<?php echo $nomepro ?>&preco=<?php echo $precopro ?> class="btn twitter" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $nomepro ?> - CONFIRMA O PEDIDO?')">

<h3 class="heading-title"><?php echo $nomepro ?>&nbsp R$<?php echo $precopro ?></h3> </a>
```

A IF que troca a imagem quando indisponivel esta assim:

```
 $sqlp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_categoria='11'");
    while($verp = mysql_fetch_array($sqlp)){
        $disponivel = $verp['disponivel'];
        $id_pro = $verp['cod'];
        $nomepro = $verp['nome'];
        $descpro = $verp['descricao'];
        $precopro = $verp['preco'];





        if($disponivel == SIM){
            $img = "../imagens/disponivel.png"; 


        }else{
        $img = "../imagens/indisponivel.png";

        }
```

Estou usando jquery (sem conhecer) se alguem tiver alguma ideia, Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
...
while($verp = mysql_fetch_array($sqlp)){
    if($rs['disponivel']){
        $estado = "inactivo";
    } else {
        $estado = "activo";
    }
print "<a href=\"#\" name=\"{$rs['cod']}\" class=\"item {$estado}\">{$rs['nome']}</a><br>";
}
?>

<script>
(function(){
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('a.item');

    el.forEach(function(a){
        a.addEventListener('click', function(m){
            if(a.classList.contains('inativo')){
                m.preventDefault();
                alert('inativo');
            }

        }, false);
    });

})();
</script>
```

O campo`disponível` poderia ser um `1` ou `0`.